# 'Autofocus' attribute works once, but not twice, on input elements

Tags: javascript, html, forms, d3.js, focus

I code in d3.js, and sometimes use `input` elements to, well, gather input from the user without using a `form`. This works fine.

But I notice I can't apply the `autofocus` attribute consistently on a dynamic page; it works only the first time it's applied.

An example is below, with all coding. Notice how `autofocus` works perfectly the first time the `input` element appears. It doesn't work at all the second time, even though the coding is the same.

Fixing this would improve the UX on smartphones in particular.

**Note:** The `.focus()` method doesn't work, and I think that's because it can only be applied to `input` elements that are part of a form.

```css
h1,
p,
input {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

input {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  color: gray;
  opacity: 0;
}

input::placeholder {
  font-weight: normal;
  color: silver;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <h1>Testing the autofocus</h1>
</div>

<script>
  // wait 2 seconds, then create input element with autofocus
  d3.timeout(function() {
    createFirstInput();
  }, 2000);

  function createFirstInput() {
    d3.select("h1")
      .text("Creating first input field")
    d3.select("#container")
      .append("input")
      .attr("type", "text")
      .attr("placeholder", "input goes here")
      .attr("autofocus", "autofocus")
      .transition()
      .duration(2000)
      .style("opacity", 1);
    d3.select("#container")
      .append("p")
      .text("autofocus works; cursor appears in input field");
    // delete input field after 5 seconds
    d3.timeout(function() {
      d3.select("h1")
        .text("Creating second input field");
      d3.selectAll("input, p")
        .remove();
      // create second input field
      createSecondInput();
    }, 5000);
  }

  function createSecondInput() {
    // wait 2 seconds, then create input element with autofocus
    d3.timeout(function() {
      d3.select("#container")
        .append("input")
        .attr("type", "text")
        .attr("placeholder", "input goes here")
        .attr("autofocus", "autofocus")
        .transition()
        .duration(2000)
        .style("opacity", 1);
      d3.select("#container")
        .append("p")
        .text("autofocus doesn't work; no cursor in input field");
    }, 2000);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [focus()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus) method does work:

```
input.node().focus();
```

Here, `input` is the D3 selection that appends the input (by the way, name your selections! It's a good practice). By using `node()` on that selection we get the actual DOM element, to which we use the `focus()` method.

Here is the demo:

```css
h1,
p,
input {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

input {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  color: gray;
  opacity: 0;
}

input::placeholder {
  font-weight: normal;
  color: silver;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <h1>Testing the autofocus</h1>
</div>

<script>
  // wait 2 seconds, then create input element with autofocus
  d3.timeout(function() {
    createFirstInput();
  }, 2000);

  function createFirstInput() {
    d3.select("h1")
      .text("Creating first input field")
    d3.select("#container")
      .append("input")
      .attr("type", "text")
      .attr("placeholder", "input goes here")
      .attr("autofocus", "autofocus")
      .transition()
      .duration(2000)
      .style("opacity", 1);
    d3.select("#container")
      .append("p")
      .text("autofocus works; cursor appears in input field");
    // delete input field after 5 seconds
    d3.timeout(function() {
      d3.select("h1")
        .text("Creating second input field");
      d3.selectAll("input, p")
        .remove();
      // create second input field
      createSecondInput();
    }, 5000);
  }

  function createSecondInput() {
    // wait 2 seconds, then create input element with autofocus
    d3.timeout(function() {
      var input = d3.select("#container")
        .append("input")
        .attr("type", "text")
        .attr("placeholder", "input goes here")
        .attr("autofocus", "autofocus")
        .transition()
        .duration(2000)
        .style("opacity", 1);
      input.node().focus();
      d3.select("#container")
        .append("p")
        .text("autofocus with focus() method does work");
    }, 2000);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Helpful as always, Gerardo! I didn't realise I had to apply the `.focus()` method to the `.node()`. Even the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus), and most web examples, suggest I can apply it directly to the `input` element. This is much more efficient than `autofocus`.

Comment: @Markus you can only apply it to the input element. That's exactly why I'm using `node()` here, otherwise you have a D3 selection, not the DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

This is because autofocus should be given to only one input element. If you want to change the focus use focus() method of node()
Here is the code.

```
<div id="container">
  <h1>Testing the autofocus</h1>
</div>

<script>
  // wait 2 seconds, then create input element with autofocus
  d3.timeout(function() {
    createFirstInput();
  }, 2000);

  function createFirstInput() {
    d3.select("h1")
      .text("Creating first input field")
    d3.select("#container")
      .append("input")
      .attr("type", "text")
      .attr("placeholder", "input goes here")
      .transition()
      .duration(2000)
      .style("opacity", 1)
      .node()
      .focus();
    d3.select("#container")
      .append("p")
      .text("autofocus works; cursor appears in input field");
    // delete input field after 5 seconds
    d3.timeout(function() {
      d3.select("h1")
        .text("Creating second input field");
      d3.selectAll("input, p")
        .remove();
      // create second input field
      createSecondInput();
    }, 5000);
  }

  function createSecondInput() {
    // wait 2 seconds, then create input element with autofocus
    d3.timeout(function() {
      var input = d3.select("#container")
        .append("input")
        .attr("type", "text")
        .attr("placeholder", "input goes here")
        .transition()
        .duration(2000)
        .style("opacity", 1)
        .node()
        .focus();
      d3.select("#container")
        .append("p")
        .text("autofocus should be given to only one input element. If you want to change the focus use focus() method of node()");
    }, 2000);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Sameer; appreciate the heads-up about using `.node()` (I was unaware of the need for it). However, I'm wondering _why_ `autofocus` didn't work. I only ever applied it to one element at a time, and I removed that element before applying `autofocus` to a new one.